# SCSS, Compass and GULP: How to minify without breaking CSS?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, compass, gulp-sass

I am using [Gulp-Compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass)  and want to minify my CSS.

When I do this, the following code

```
.tags-bar .sub-bullet:nth-last-of-type {
display:none; 
}

.ux-panel-hidden{
display:none;
}
```

becomes minified to:

```
.tags-bar .sub-bullet:nth-last-of-type,.ux-panel-hidden{display:none}
```

The `:nth-type` part confuses the browser, so the `ux-panel-hidden` doesn't get read.

[JSFiddle with minified code](https://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/47gLx2j8/)

[JSfildde with non-minified code](https://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/ksty7veo/1/)

`tags-bar` and `ux-panel` are in separate _scss files, so I am not sure why the minfication brings them together.

How can I fix it?

Here is my Gulp Code:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    return gulp.src('frontend/build/css/*.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            css: 'frontend/dist/css',
            sass: 'frontend/build/css',
            image: 'frontend/images/',
            font: 'stylesheets/fonts',
            require: ['susy', 'breakpoint'],
            bundle_exec: true
        }))
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend/dist/css'))
        .pipe(rename({
         suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend/dist/css'))
        .pipe(notify({ // Add gulpif here
            sound: "Pop"
        }));
});
```

Comment: Voting to close due to typographical error.  Try validating your CSS.  Browsers will ignore the entire selector if it contains a single thing they don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:nth-last-of-type` is not valid syntax since it requires an argument to be passed eg. `:nth-last-of-type(odd)`

This may be causing your issue.

More reading on the property at CSS-Tricks https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-of-type/